# Why isn't my fixture created once per package with the `"package"` scope?

Tags: pytest, pytest-fixtures

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the [`"package"` fixture scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixture-scopes).

I have two tests placed in two different packages, but the fixture with `"package"` scope only seems generated once while I would've expected it to be generated twice.

Why?

## MRE :

### Directory structure :

```
> tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── conftest.py
├── pkg1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_scope.py
└── pkg2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_scope.py

2 directories, 6 files
```

### Files :

- `__init__.py` files are empty.
- `conftest.py` :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="package")
def my_fixture():
    print("Package fixture invoked!")
```

- `test_scope.py` files :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def test_(my_fixture):
    pass
```

### Result :

```
> pytest -s
============================ test session starts ============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.12, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/dojo-pytest/notebook/tests/concepts/fixtures/scope/pb
collected 2 items                                                           

pkg1/test_scope.py Package fixture invoked!
.
pkg2/test_scope.py .

============================= 2 passed in 0.01s =============================
```

### Expected result :

```
> pytest -s
============================ test session starts ============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.12, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: /home/vmonteco/dojo-pytest/notebook/tests/concepts/fixtures/scope/pb
collected 2 items                                                           

pkg1/test_scope.py Package fixture invoked!
.
pkg2/test_scope.py Package fixture invoked!
.

============================= 2 passed in 0.01s =============================
```

Answer (score 0):

You have nested packages here, specifically `pb` (judging by the pytest log) with the sub-packages `pkg1` and `pkg2`. The question now is which of these packages is used for the package scope.

From what I understand from a glance at the [source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2c5c97b6d150b21860ac18a40856f960b5fbcbf8/src/_pytest/fixtures.py#L116), the package is defined by the location of the fixture, e.g. in your case it would be the top-level package where the `conftest.py` with the fixture resides (`pb`), and the package will contain both sub-packages `pkg1` and `pkg2`.

To make it work as you expect, you have to move/copy the `conftest.py` into both packages (at least the part with the package-scoped fixture).

Thinking about this, this is probably the only way to have a consistent behavior in the case of nested packages. The tests where the fixture is applied may reside in different (sub-)packages, and using the test location to define the package could result in undefined behavior, as the package scope could be different between these tests.

*Side note:*
While this is somewhat logical if thinking about it (never having used package scope myself, this was the first time I thought about this), I would appreciate a more clear explanation in the `pytest` documentation. It probably makes sense to make a documentation PR for this case...

*Edit:*

The pytest documentation now reads (emphasis mine):

> *package*: the fixture is destroyed during teardown of the last test **in the package where the fixture is defined**, including sub-packages and sub-directories within it.

This should make it a bit clearer.